# Enabling GZIP is GWT application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt, gzip

I'm working on pay load optimization.

Here I read that [compress your responses in to GZIP](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip),

So I [Configuring the CompressionFilter](https://code.google.com/p/webutilities/wiki/CompressionFilter#About_these_patterns)

And configured the below filter to compress my responses to gzip,

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>compressionFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.webutilities.filters.CompressionFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>   
       <param-name>compressionThreshold</param-name>  
       <param-value>1024</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>   
       <param-name>ignoreMimes</param-name>  
       <param-value>images/*,video/*, multipart/x-gzip</param-value>
    </init-param>  

 </filter>  
 <filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>compressionFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
 </filter-mapping>
```

It's working fine for not files like js,html,css.. etc.. but  where as for the Ajax response I'm unable to make it work.

I'm using GWT RPC calls which by default a gzip response, My assumption is that it is trying to gzip again which is already a gzip response and giving me the exception.

StackOverFlow not allowing to paste the StackTrace even. So adding an image.

[image]

Any help in this ? Anything i'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution for your problem, but it could help to solve the basic problem (implementing gzip compression for your application) a little bit different...

If possible, I would always use Apache (or nginx) as frontend server. Regarding gzip compression Apache should be faster (pure C implementation of gzip). Be aware that in addition to gzipping this setup provides much more nice stuff:

- Setting correct cache header (e.g. for *.cache.html files)
- Deliver error pages if Servlet container is down
- Reducing the number of requests to be handled by the Servlet container by caching/delivering static resources by the frontend server
- you can even use pre-gzipped versions of your static resources to not compress the same stuff over and over again (https://code.google.com/p/zopfli/ can be helpful to reduce the size of pre-gzipped resources)

There are certainly even more advantages, but I'm not a Ops person.